# videojs show double caption (it may be already posted but didnt found similair issue)

Tags: video.js, captions

im facing a weird problem and i dont know how to resolve it,
videojs show me double caption for arabic subtitles but show correctly other languages like french english even chinese. so im just wondering what should be the issue. I checked the file vtt but it seems correct.

here a picture how it looks like [see image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8jLq.png)

Comment: comon pls any help ?

Comment: A [mcve] would help

Answer (score 0):

well heres the minimal informations that i can provide:
the config is : 
i put the real of the second subtitle to verify that is not doubled but in videojs shows double captions only for arabic

```
<video id="example_video_1" class="video-js" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264" data-setup='{"example_option":true}'><source src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" type="video/mp4" /><track kind="captions" src="http://example.com/path/to/captions.vtt" srclang="en" label="English" default><track kind="captions"src="https://www.osnmovies.com/subtitles/tt0918940_ar/0000.vtt"srclang="ar" label="Arabic" default> </video>
```

Comment: still cant find out a solution for my issue